# Updating dependent properties using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Some properties on my `viewmodel`:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

public int Count
{
    get { return Tasks.Count; }
}

public int Completed
{
    get { return Tasks.Count(t => t.IsComplete); }
}
```

What's the best way to update these properties when `Tasks` changes?

*My current method*:

```cs
public TaskViewModel()
{
    Tasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>(repository.LoadTasks());
    Tasks.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => 
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Count");
            OnPropertyChanged("Completed");
        };
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With respect to `Count`, you don't have to do this at all. Simply bind to `Tasks.Count` and your bindings will get notified of the change by the `ObservableCollection`.

`Completed` is a different story, because this is outside of `ObservableCollection`. Still, from the level of the abstraction/interface, you really want `Completed` to be a property of that `Tasks` collection.

For this, I think a better approach would be to create "sub" view-model for your `Tasks` property:

```
public class TasksViewModel : ObservableCollection<Task>
{
    public int Completed
    {
        get { return this.Count(t => t.IsComplete); }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        if(e.PropertyName == "Count") NotifyCompletedChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        NotifyCompletedChanged();
    }

    void NotifyCompletedChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(_completedChangedArgs);
    }
    readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs _completedChangedArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Completed");
}
```

This gives you all of the benefits of the `ObservableCollection`, and effectively makes the `Completed` property part of it. We still haven't captured only the cases where the number of completed items truly changes, but we have reduced the number of redundant notifications somewhat.

Now the viewmodel just has the property:

```
public TasksViewModel Tasks { get; set; }
```

…and you can bind to `Tasks`, `Tasks.Count`, and `Tasks.Completed` with ease.

---

As an alternative, if you would rather create these other properties on the "main" view-model, you can take this notion of a subclassed `ObservableCollection<T>` to create one with some method where you can pass in an `Action<string>` delegate, which would represent raising a property change notification on the main view-model, and some list of property names. This collection could then effectively raise the property change notifications on the view-model:

```
public class ObservableCollectionWithSubscribers<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    Action<string> _notificationAction = s => { }; // do nothing, by default
    readonly IList<string> _subscribedProperties = new List<string>();

    public void SubscribeToChanges(Action<string> notificationAction, params string[] properties)
    {
        _notificationAction = notificationAction;

        foreach (var property in properties)
            _subscribedProperties.Add(property);
    }


    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        NotifySubscribers();
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        NotifySubscribers();
    }

    void NotifySubscribers()
    {
        foreach (var property in _subscribedProperties)
            _notificationAction(property);
    }
}
```

You could even leave the property type as `ObservableCollection<Task>`.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        var tasks = new ObservableCollectionWithSubscribers<Task>();
        tasks.SubscribeToChanges(Notify, "Completed");
        Tasks = tasks;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get; private set; }

    public int Completed
    {
        get { return Tasks.Count(t => t.IsComplete); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void Notify(string property)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

Comment: That is certainly a better design.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Looks rather elegant to me. I really don't know how you'd make that more succinct.</strike>

<strike>*(How odd to write an answer like this. If somebody actually comes up with something more elegant, I might delete this.)*</strike>

Okay, I noticed one thing, unrelated to the original question: Your `Tasks` property has a public setter. Make it `private set;`, or you'll need to implement the `set` with a backing field so you can remove the delegate on the previous instance, replace and wire up the new one, and do `OnPropertyChanged` with "Tasks", "Count", and "Completed". *(And seeing how `Tasks` is set in the constructor, I'm guessing `private set;` is the better option.)*

Doesn't make notifying about `Count` and `Completed` more elegant, but it fixes a bug.

And many MVVM frameworks get the property name from a lambda, so that instead of `OnPropertyChanged("Count")`, you can write `OnPropertyChanged(() => Count)` so that it will follow renames done with the help of refactoring tools. I don't think renaming happens all that often, though, but it does avoid some string literals.